# A problem in Differential Equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> Find the Laplace transform of the following:
>   $$ f(t) = \begin{cases} 0, & t<1,\\ t^2-2t+2, & t \ge 1\end{cases} $$

My solution:

$ u_1f(t-1)=u_1(t)(t^2-2t+2) $

$ f(t-1)=t^2-2t+2$

$f(t)=(t+1)^2-2(t+1)+2=t^2+2t+1-t-2+2=t^2+1$

$ f(s)=Laplace(t^2+1)= 2/s^3+ 1/s $

Final answer:

$ e^{-s} \left( 2/s^3+1/s\right) $

Comment: Your final answer is correct.

Comment: awesome thanks for your input